# Is it easy to get a cab in Palm Springs?

Tags: public-transport, taxis, southern-california

I'm wondering if it's easy to get around Palm Springs by either taxis or transit? We were thinking of renting a car at Budget Palm Springs, CA Car Rentals (P2W) which is only 1 mile from the airport as the cost is considerably cheaper than from the airport location, but will it be easy to get a ride to the airport?

Comment: The nearest bus stop is about 400 meter walk from the airport terminal entrance. You'll need a transfer or two to get to the other Budget location though. If the price difference is that much, I'd taxi or Uber it over there. If not, just rent at the airport.

Comment: How would you define "easy"? I define it as greater than 147 Standard Easiness Units, but that's just me, plus I don't know what the conversion is to metric. :-)

Comment: @choster 147 SEU converts to 74.1µƎ (pronounced micro-ease). As a comparison, using a La-Z-Boy recliner clocks in at 192µƎ and constructing anything from IKEA without no hextools is 452,733.2µƎ. Now you know.

Answer (score 2):

[Uber](https://www.uber.com/en-CZ/cities/palm-springs/) is available in Palm Springs. You therefore shouldn't have any issues getting a cab, especially when coming from the airport.